# I always get an extra backslash when using them as escape sign in Python 3.7.11

Tags: python, string

The problem is very simple, when I input:

```
"\"\"'"
```

The output is

```
"""\'"
```

And when I input:

```
"C:\\Document\\code\\data1.csv"
```

The output is

```
"C:\\Document\\code\\data1.csv"
```

However, when I input:

```
r"C:\Documents\code\data2.csv"
```

The output is

```
"C:\\Documents\\code\\data2.csv"
```

Where did these extra backslashes come from? By the standard semantics of the backslash it acts as escape sign, but how could they "copy" itself and appears in the positions so that it seems like popped from nowhere?

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I understood... When I simply put an "enter" after the command line, it returns me that very command.

If I place the string into functions like `print()`, then I will get the result I want.